# Have difficulty understanding phonegap android vs webview

Tags: android, cordova

I have a problem understanding how phonegap works and i cannot find the answer in docs.

I installed phonegap on windows and phone device and played around with codes in www/* folder.

However, when I use phonegap-build to make my android app it extracted the files from platforms/browser but not the www/*

I know it sounds stupid but should i make different apps for different devices in different folders?, i know this cannot be true. so my question is:

If I make an app inside www/index.html how can I convert them to android .apk app?

Comment: if you use phonegap build you have to upload the www content only, not the whole phonegap project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) used to display web pages in native applications. But, [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) is a tool which is used to develop hybrid applications using html and javascript. Don't confuse with Android webview and phonegap. Both used for different purpose. You have to use separate folder for each projects.

[Converting Your Phonegap App to an Android App w/ PhoneGap](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-10-22-how-to-convert-your-javascript-app-into-an-android-app-with-phonegap/)

[Difference between a native application and a cross-platform mobile application](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-native-application-and-a-cross-platform-mobile-application)